# Aurelia: Custom Elements vs Custom Attributes

Tags: jquery-ui, aurelia

I would like to know what's the difference between using custom elements or custom attributes in Aurelia.

I am using a datepicker from jqueryUI. I implemented it as a custom attribute(following this https://www.danyow.net/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-aurelia/) and it works perfectly. I wasn't able to make it into a custom element tough. I looked around and found some examples online but they didn't work.

I want to know if there are any disadvantages to using custom attributes in place of custom elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A **custom attribute** is for extending the functionality of an existing HTML Element and actually have *no view*. Like in your example you want to extend the functionality of an input field. It shall look like an input, have standard focus/form/validation etc. input behaviour and so on ( if `<input type="date"/>` would be proper implemented in all browser we would surely use this instead of jquery-datepicker ).

**custom elements** are a possibility to write your own reusable element inclusive *an own view* and own functionality and logic.

Examples:

**custom element**

- self made datepicker (need to show some dates and so on = view)
- own autocomplete input (you will need view for showing a list)
- recurring ui-elements (e.g. a data, image pair where the image shall always on the left side and do something on click, 5 lines html and logic wrapped in one custom element)

**custom attribute**

- use a 3rd party Datepicker (like jQuery-ui, which will just do a jQuery call to add a view programatically)
- use google maps places autocomplete (just an api call which will change the input value and show dynamically added view, no own view)
- an image which shall have special behaviour ( like a image which will make a rest call and change the image)

Comment: Tnx for the explanation. A bit off topic, when creating custom elements, I see @bindable. What is it used for? I saw something about allowing attributes to be binded  to but I don't use it and things seem to work.

Comment: The @bindable decorator is used to indicate that a field in your custom element's view model can be used as an attribute